# Google Sheets - How to move a row to bottom of sheet when "Status" is changed to a value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I need some help! I've done a bunch of research but wasn't able to figure this out.

I'm trying to figure out how to get a row moved to the bottom once the Status `F` column value is changed. Here is an example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rFliETuAY-uzkgsLJJlaXC_9k0Fg0CkPPnn_v3ExwUY/edit?usp=sharing

This page will fill up so I need the ones that have no status to stay up top while the ones that have have a status to go below the top ones. Once the status is changed it is complete but i still need the data.

Comment: Make the sheet public so we can see it. Right now it requires access.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's public now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

You clearly need an `onEdit()` trigger. Namely, as soon as the status is changed to any value (different than blank) the row will automatically be shifted to the bottom.

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(as.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 6  && row > 1 && !as.getRange(row,col).getValue()=='') {  
    const row_new = as.getRange(row,1,1,col);
    row_new.copyTo(as.getRange(as.getLastRow()+1,1,1,col));
    as.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

### Instructions:

- Click on **Tools** => **Script editor**:

[image: example]

- **Copy/Paste** the aforementioned code snippet to a blank script file and click on **save**:

[image: example2]

- You are done! Everytime you change the status in **column F** to **a
  non blank value** the row is shifted to the bottom. Keep in mind the
  name of the sheet must be **Sheet1** in order for the code to work.
  If you want to change the name of the sheet, you should adjust the
  script accordingly.

### Illustration:

[image: illustration]

Comment: I added the script but it doesn't move the rows to the bottom. It gives me an error when I change the status.

Comment: @Dede what is the error message you are getting? Also make sure you followed the instructions of my answer correctly.

Comment: When I change the status it says: There was a problem
The cell you are trying to edit may have been moved or deleted." I followed your directions and changed nothing. I've refreshed and the rows still don't move. Thanks!

Comment: @Dede see the last section of my answer. As soon as you change the status of the item, you just wait until the transfer of the row is made. Don't click random buttons after that. See the gif I uploaded.

Comment: I see what was happening! I changed the drop down to what was already chosen and it wouldn't go so when I change it to another status then it moves down. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> *...I need the ones that have no status to stay up top while the ones that have have a status to go below the top ones. Once the status is changed it is complete but i still need the data.*

You **could probably** use the following formula, adjusting ranges to your needs

```
={query(A1:C22,"where A is not null and C is null",1);
  query(A2:C22,"where A is not null and not C is null")}
```

This is a wild guess since as [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63567569/google-sheets-how-to-move-a-row-to-bottom-of-sheet-when-status-is-changed-to#comment112408052_63567569) you provide almost zero information.

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: That is also a great solution !