# Automatically move rows to the bottom of the same sheet (Google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to move an entire row at the bottom of the same sheet once (column H) becomes "0".

I have an inventory sheet that I want to check if an item is out of stock by scrolling down to the bottom to see which I need to restock.

I am new with google sheets so please provide specific steps, if possible, like where to add the code.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63567569/google-sheets-how-to-move-a-row-to-bottom-of-sheet-when-status-is-changed-to ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by automatically sort the sheet

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  if(editedCell.getColumn() == 8){   
    var range = sheet.getRange("A2:H"+sheet.getLastRow());
    range.sort( { column : 8, ascending: false } );
  }
}
```

The advantage of this method is that

- you can clear the status, the line will be automatically repositioned
- you can manage different statuses
- you can add a date in the sorting process

Comment: Thank you! May I know where I am supposed to add this script? Sorry. I am super newbie to this.

Comment: Copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet (see Menu : Extension > App Scripts) and save the script by clicking on the disk icone. Here is an example : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mvOK6h3NEo9xr1maSLiTbDm7uUPU99Iv77_m3M352zk/copy